# Saving a file in postgres database using native query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

I am trying to save a file in the database. I am able to save using SQL it works perfectly fine. What I am avoiding with SQL is providing password directly in the code that why I am considering using native query. I am unsure if I can still use SQL without providing password and username directly in the code.The code for the SQL is as below

```
 try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb", "postgres",
                "postgres");

        System.out.println("......Now attempting to insert the record.....");
       // String matid = "007N00030000001";

        File file = new File("C://JavaWorkspace/pdf-sample.pdf");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cli.documents VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int)file.length());
        ps.setString(2, "1");
        ps.setString(3, file.getName());
        ps.setString(4,matid);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        fis.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If using native query I cant see any method that I can use instead of 
**ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int)file.length());**
there is only setParameter 
below is my attempt using native query

```
          Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO cli.documents (matid, doctype,upload,docfile) " +
               " VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
       EntityManagerFactory emfactory=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "junit" );
       EntityManager em = emfactory.createEntityManager( ); //= null;
       EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
       et.begin();
        em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO cli.documents (matid, doctype,upload,docfile) " +  " VALUES(?,?,?,?)")
        .setParameter(1,matid)
        .setParameter(2, "1")
        .setParameter(3, file.getName())
        .setParameter(4, (int)file.length());
        //.setBinaryStream(4, fis, (int)file.length())
        // em.executeUpdate()
        et.commit();
```

Comment: What is your question? There is no connection between having to supply a database password and inserting data from a file.

Comment: Hie sorry for being unclear . For the code provided above using sql it does what I am trying to do but as you can see from the code there is password to connect to the database using SQL thats what I am trying to avoid. Thats why I am thinking of these other methods native query ,HQL etc where the password to access the database can be in persistence.xml